# SessionStorage to save DIV display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

Can I set the display style of my div using session storage? I have a button and when the button is clicked it will display another div that is normally hidden. 
I would like for it to set if it has been clicked and then remember the state after the page is refreshed?

Here is my code:

```
<button id="ShopParts">Shop Parts</button>

$("#ShopParts").click(function() {
  $("#shop_vehicle_container").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: So you want that display css of `$("#shop_vehicle_container")` should remain the same as previous after page refresh.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("shop-vehicle"))
    {
        $("#shop_vehicle_container").css("display", sessionStorage.getItem("shop-vehicle"));
    }
});
$("#ShopParts").click(function () {
    $("#shop_vehicle_container").css("display", "block");
    sessionStorage.setItem("shop-vehicle", $("#shop_vehicle_container").css("display"));
});
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! this was exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
var el = $('#shop_vehicle_container');
var style = el.css('display');

// Store
localStorage.setItem("savedstyle", style);
// Retrieve & set
el.css('display', localStorage.getItem("savedstyle"));
```

Remember to check for Storage browser support.

Answer (score 0):

cookies work too..

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
    var cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ";";
    document.cookie = cookie;
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var regexp = new RegExp("(?:^" + name + "|;\s*"+ name + ")=(.*?)(?:;|$)", "g");
  var result = regexp.exec(document.cookie);
  return (result === null) ? null : result[1];
}
```